# Git Copy a folder from master branch to another branch

Tags: git, github

I have folder name `utils` I want to `copy` this folder from `master` branch to `work` branch. How do I do that ?

Comment: You mean you don't want it on `master` anymore, but you *do* want it on `work`? Or you just want to copy it over to `work`?

Comment: @CarlNorum question updated

Comment: I believe you can use `git subtree push` to do this with one command.  See https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490 for example.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To copy the folder over:

```
$ git checkout work
Switched to branch 'work'
$ git checkout master -- utils
$ git add utils
$ git commit -m "Adding 'utils' directory from 'master' branch."
[work 9fcd968] Adding 'utils' directory from 'master' branch.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 utils/file
```

If you want to delete it on `master` after that:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git rm -r utils
rm 'utils/file'
$ git commit -m "Removing 'utils' directory."
[master c786f95] Removing 'utils' directory.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 utils/file
```

Then you can just `git push` as necessary.  Git's output in your project may be different; I just made a simple test repo here with only one file in the `utils` directory.

Comment: Just for consideration, when `work` and `master` get merged again there will be a conflict because of the different operations that happened on each side.

Comment: Interestingly I tried this. And when I merged my branch back to ```master```, I had no conflict. Maybe git has gotten smarter?

Comment: I had an issue but I fixed it adding origin: git checkout origin/master -- PUBLISH

Comment: @Carl Norum does the `copy` example also applies to changing the ALREADY EXISTING IN WORK BRANCH `utils` folder onto the `master` version?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - if you want to get changes from your work branch back onto maaster, just rebase or merge.

Comment: This adds the entire folder utils in the branch. I want just the contents of utils to be in the branch. How to do that?

Comment: Make whatever layout changes you want after the `git checkout master -- utils` step and then change the `add` step to match what you actually want your branch to have.